# create dropdown in generated csv file

Tags: php, csv

Is it possible to using php can we give drop-down in export csv file for sorting purpose?

I want to export csv file in which we have some sort drop down like how much usage of internet and how much duration all that kind of stuff using php

If yes 
will you please provide me some good links which i didn't get from google
If no 
which is better option for this kind of csv stuff

Example :

CSV FILE :

Columns : 
    Username | Duration(IN HRS) | Using Internet(In Mb)

```
Ankit    | 2:00:00          | 200
Divyesh  | 3:30:00          | 150
Bhavik   | 1:00:00          | 300
```

By default sorting by Duration
If i am select dropdown by Using Internet
Then need to show like below records

```
Username | Duration(IN HRS) | Using Internet(In Mb)

Divyesh  | 3:30:00          | 150
Ankit    | 2:00:00          | 200
Bhavik   | 1:00:00          | 300
```

Comment: I think you are looking for an excel-sheet instead of a CSV file... CSV is just text, no extra operations can be added. In Excel files you can do this, but it is much more difficult to generate Excel files from PHP than CSV files

Answer (score 0):

No, CSV file can't have any style or functionnality like this, they are only for storage.